# Read multiple single column text files (varying length) to data frame where filename is column header

Tags: r, data-processing

I have many (600+) text files which each contain only a single column of data which I would like to read into a data frame in R. The catch is I need the values from each file to be imported as a separate column and the number of values in each file is not equal. The text files all start with the heading 'Area' which I don't need (I am trying to set the filename as the header instead) and then proceed with a column of numbers (4000 - 10000 values) e.g.

```
Area
0.0034556
0.0002345
....
```

The closest I have come is with:

```
filenames <-dir()
n <- length(filenames)
for (i in 1:n) {data[i] <- read.csv(filenames[i]}
## printing data at this point gives lists for each value of i
```

I tried then to rbind the value containing lists to the filenames to use as individual columns (under the variable c) I was then hoping to piece together the individual columns to a dataframe:

```
for (i in 1:n) {c[i] <- rbind(filenames[i], data[i])}
```

When c is printed though this seems to give a list with two elements - the name of the last file and the number of values it contains.

I am concerned that even if I can bind the lists imported with read.csv to the column headers I still won't be able to combine this into a dataframe because the number of values varies between files. I have seen may solutions for combining the values of multiple text files into a single column (and have got this working) - but can't find a solution to this problem where each imported file needs its own column online or in swirl.

I would be grateful for any help!
Angus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the large data volume I suggest to use `data.table`.

#### Step 1: Read all files in one `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
filenames <-dir()
dt_long <- rbindlist(setNames(lapply(filenames, fread), filenames), idcol = TRUE)
dtl
#         .id      Area
#1: file1.csv 0.0034556
#2: file1.csv 0.0002345
#3: file2.csv 0.0034556
#4: file2.csv 0.0002345
#5: file2.csv 0.0034556
#6: file2.csv 0.0002345
#7: file2.csv 0.0034556
#8: file2.csv 0.0002345
```

`fread` reads each file within the `lapply` call. `lapply` is a kind of implied for loop over the filenames and returns a list where each list element contains a `data.table` with the contents of one file.

`setNames` is used to rename each list element with the corresponding file name.

Finally, `rbindlist` combines the single `data.tables` from the list into one large `data.table`. The origin of each row is identified by the `.id` col.

#### Step 2: Reshape to wide format

Usually, I prefer to work with data in long format because I can use grouping functions (e.g., `by = .id` in `data.table` syntax) which affect the data of all files simultaneously.

However, if you insist to have a separate column for each file you can reshape from wide to long format:

```
dt_wide <- dcast(dt_long, rowid(.id) ~ .id, value.var = "Area")
dt_wide
#   .id file1.csv file2.csv
#1:   1 0.0034556 0.0034556
#2:   2 0.0002345 0.0002345
#3:   3        NA 0.0034556
#4:   4        NA 0.0002345
#5:   5        NA 0.0034556
#6:   6        NA 0.0002345
```

Note that missing values due to different file sizes have been filled up by `NA`.

#### Data

In order to have a reproducible example, I created two dummy data files

**file1.csv**

```
Area
0.0034556
0.0002345
```

**file2.csv**

```
Area
0.0034556
0.0002345
0.0034556
0.0002345
0.0034556
0.0002345
```

Comment: using `idcol = 'id'` avoids getting a dot in the columnname

Comment: @Jaap Yes, that's true. You can specify an arbitrary name for the id colum, but I deliberately choose to stay with the default name. Is there a specific reason why a column name starting with a dot should be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest to do is to put everything in a list. In the function `read.csv` you can define the column names immediately with `col.names`.

```
filenames <-dir()
n <- length(filenames)
data <- list()
for (i in 1:n) {data[[i]] <- read.csv(filenames[i], col.names = filenames[i])}
```